# Mysql Multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[image]

I try to get this query to work.

It seems to work until I join the albums table, when all of the data disappears.

Can someone please explain?
[image]

[image]

album table
Orderitems table
[image]

[image]

Product table

Comment: Do the selected products have album ids that are valid?

Comment: can you show us your album table. it looks like you don't have any matching album with products.albumid.

Comment: what are the contents of the album table ?

Comment: only one order has a album in it. but that order does not show up
orderid 3's product id relates to a album.

Comment: If an order has an album in it, then are you not supposed to join album on order instead of product?

Comment: @user3075549. make sure the orderitems in tha order are related to one valid product, that in turn is related to an album. your query is ok, but your data looks like it isnt

Comment: i have added the album table to the question

Comment: Can you show the product table as well?

Comment: i have shown the order item table i will now add the product table which is where the issue may lie tbh

Comment: the order is there. and it is related to a product which is then related to an album

Comment: now I'm getting an error sql logic error or database missing! my order table has gone!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your first query using the "JOIN", which is why there are no results.
if you want to have results, maybe you could use a "LEFT JOIN"

Answer (score 0):

I think is you OrderItems table data got problem.Join table must all condition match the data will selected, if one of the join statement no valid the data will not selected.But you OrderItems table show either song_id null or album_id null,but you sql mean song_id and album_id match just only got data.Kindly measure song_id and album_id both column not null and match

[image]

Comment: since you OrderItems item got song_id,album_id and product_id why not you all join on condition point to OrderItems?

Comment: I changed songid and albumid to not null, which changed all the null's to 0. but i get the same result

Comment: I got it to work to an extent by changing the join to a left join. Is this incorrect? it gives me all of the orders but is there a better way?

Comment: select customername,o.orderid,p.productid,s.songtitle,a.albumtitle
from orders o
join customers c on c.customerid=o.customerid
join orderitems oi on oi.orderid=o.orderid
join products p on p.productid=oi.productid
join songs s on s.songid=oi.songid
join albums a on a.albumid=oi.albumid

and measure you albumid and songid both is match

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your join to the song table. In your product table the song id is null for the only entry with a album order, which is doing an inner join and hence removing the entry.

My suggestion would be to do a left join on both the song and album table, just to see what you're working with.